# How to check Alert Dialog visibility?

Tags: java, android

I want to check alert dialog is visible or not. In most post I saw that they used isShowing, but seems like its not describable now.

When user click info textview, I pause music. If user close alert dialog, music will be play again.

```
info_Button.setClickable(true);
    info_Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mediaControl.pause();
            AlertDialog.Builder playstopbutton_builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(exercise_arm_triceps_execute.this);
            playstopbutton_builder.setTitle("WARNING").setMessage("Please get warm before exercising!");
            playstopbutton_builder.create().show();
            playstopbutton_builder.setCancelable(false);

            //if alert dialog is visible keep music paused
            //else if mediaControl.start();

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to add an OnDismissListener to the playstopbutton_builder:

```
        playstopbutton_builder.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
            mediaControl.start();
        }
    });
```

This way, when the user dismisses the Alert Dialog, the music will start to play again.

EDIT: if the OnDismissListener approach is not desired, maybe something like this would be better:

```
public void infoClickHandler(View v) {
    mediaControl.pause();

    AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    b.setMessage("restart the music?");
    b.setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            mediaControl.start();
        }
    });
    b.show();
}
```

EDIT 2: On the other hand, if the dialog cannot have positive or negative buttons, and you do not want to set cancellable to false, this seems to work:

```
public void infoClickHandler(View v) {
    mediaControl.pause();

    AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    b.setMessage("restart the music?");
    b.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
            if (!mediaControl.isPlaying()) {
                mediaControl.start();
            }
        }
    });
    b.show();
}
```

The OnDismissListener will be called when the user clicks outside of the dialog box.

Comment: I placed it inside of "info_Button.setOnClickListener" but didn't resume the sound.

Comment: Thanks Albert, but as I sad the other friend, I shouldn't add positive-negative buttons to this alert dialog. I need to check if user click somewhere around or back button. Detecting back button is okey but what about around of alert dialog? By the way, I removed setcancelable.

Answer (score 1):

since you have made Cancelable false, you might need to use

**for positive button say like a okay**

```
playstopbutton_builder.setPositiveButton(positiveBtnText,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    //resume ur media player here
                }
            })
```

**for negative button say like a cancel**

```
playstopbutton_builder.setNegativeButton(negativeBtnText,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    //resume ur media player here
                }
            })
```

**so it would look like this**

```
info_Button.setClickable(true);
info_Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        mediaControl.pause();
        AlertDialog.Builder playstopbutton_builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(exercise_arm_triceps_execute.this);
        playstopbutton_builder.setTitle("WARNING").setMessage("Please get warm before exercising!");
        playstopbutton_builder.create().show();
        playstopbutton_builder.setCancelable(false);
playstopbutton_builder.setPositiveButton(positiveBtnText,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    //resume ur media player here
                }
            });
playstopbutton_builder.setNegativeButton(negativeBtnText,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    //resume ur media player here
                }
            });
    }
});
```

Comment: Hello, I shouldn't add positive-negative buttons to that Alert Dialog.
My alert dialog is just for info. When user sees it, music will be paused (i did this part with alertdialog.setonclicklistener), but if user click somewhere around or back button. I want it to be resumed. (by the way i removed setcancelable(

Comment: you might have to remove setcancelable(false) in that case and use a dismislistener as suggested by other, hope that helps :)

Comment: I used this, but didn't help


 playstopbutton_builder.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                        mediaControl.start();
                    }
                });

Comment: did you try to debug, whr the code ctrl is going, check whether u get a call back on to onDismiss method

Answer (score 0):

You need to check dialog show or not change you code like this.

```
info_Button.setClickable(true); 
    info_Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
        @Override 
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mediaControl.pause(); 
            AlertDialog.Builder playstopbutton_builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(exercise_arm_triceps_execute.this);
            playstopbutton_builder.setTitle("WARNING").setMessage("Please get warm before exercising!");
            playstopbutton_builder.create();
            playstopbutton_builder.setCancelable(false);

            //if alert dialog is visible keep music paused 
            //else if mediaControl.start(); 

            if(!playstopbutton_builder.isShowing()){ 

  //if its visibility is not showing then show here 

                  playstopbutton_builder.show();  

             }else{ 

  //do something here... if already showing 

             } 

        } 
    });
```

Comment: Thanks but It says "cannot resolve method" for 'isShowing'. I placed it just like you did. Also, in question I sad that I have problem with isShowing.